# Laravel Queue Sending immediately rather than delaying and data not stored in database

Tags: php, laravel

I am attempting to send multiple emails by queueing the mails. My mails are been sent out immediately instead of respecting the delay I set.

```js
//in controller
SendMailOfficeAssignment::dispatch($email, $fullname, $officeName)->delay(now()->addMinutes(5));
```

The mailing class:

```js
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class OfficeAssignmentNotification extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    ...
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->markdown('emails.the_mail');
    }
}
```

The job created:

```js
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

class SendMailOfficeAssignment implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
    ...
    public function handle()
    {
        sendMailHelperFunction($this->param1, '\App\Mail\OfficeAssignmentNotification', [$this->param2, $this->param3]);
    }
}
```

I have both

```js
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

I ran this earlier as well:

```js
php artisan queue:table
php artisan migrate
```

Nothing get's stored on the database however.

I have also tried both of this in my database:

```js
QUEUE_DRIVER=database
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
```

Answer (score 0):

use later() like below:

```
$when = now()->addMinutes(10);
SendMailOfficeAssignment::dispatch($email, $fullname, $officeName)
->later($when,"send-mail-job");
```